# Passing parameter to php page without form

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am new to PHP.

I have a page that displays user profile. I need to pass user id to this page
so that correct profile was displayed.

I just dont use the `<form>` element. I want to have a link

`<a href="/users/24378234298734">` or `<a href="/users/?id=24378234298734">`
or whatever

Since I am not using form I cannot use _GET or _POST on the handler page
What is the best way to handle the parameters on handler page?

Comment: You CAN pass a parameter via url and retrieve it with $_GET

Comment: `?id=24378234298734` is a _GET.

Comment: Why downvoting? I have C++ background and I am not PHP developer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A form with `method="GET"` is just a way to build a query string automatically based on user input. Nothing prevents you using `$_GET` to read data from a manually constructed query string (and the server can't tell the difference anyway).

`<a href="/users/?id=24378234298734">` will cause `$_GET['id']` to be populated.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a link somewhere like

```
<a href="/users.php?id=24378234298734">User XY</a>
```

and you put this code on users.php:

```
echo 'Hello '.$_REQUEST['id']; // $_REQUEST catches $_GET and $_POST
```

you will be able to set up a user page for user number 24378234298734.

Answer (score 2):

Use this..

**HTML**

```
<a href="/users/?id=24378234298734">Link</a>
```

**PHP**

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it is better to know if you are getting data from GET, POST or a cookie. `$_REQUEST` is best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $_GET['id'] to retrieve the value in the url /users/?id=324332. No forms are required to receive _GET variables.